# Understanding a macro

Tags: macros, racket

As I understand the macro written below; The macro takes 3 arguments and produces a struct with a constructor which accepts 3 arguments. I can guess that the line immediately following the macro definition creates a struct which looks like:
    `(struct x (+ y x))` 
I am lost in understanding how the two lines which follow that work. It appears that y is bound to an *x* *struct*, but isn't it calling the constructor with one too many arguments?

```
(define-syntax binary-search
 (syntax-rules ()
 [(binary-search (node left right))
 (struct left (node right x))]))

(binary-search (+ x y))
(define y (x 1 2 3))

(+ (x-+ y) (x-x y))
```

I won't be a bother and ask how the last line works, hopefully clarification on the *y* variable will lead me to the given answer of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's confusing here is that a field name can be the same as the struct name.
Consider this example:

```
#lang racket
(struct foo (foo) #:transparent)
(foo 42)            ; => (foo 32)
(foo-foo (foo 42))  ; => 32
```

So `(binary-search (+ x y))` results in:

```
(struct x (+ y x))
```

which defines an `x` struct that has a named also named `x`.

The line

```
(define y (x 1 2 3))
```

makes an x-struct where:

```
the + field stores 1,
the y field stores 2,
the x field stores 3.
```

Now `(x-+ y)` gets the `+` field of `y`, which is 1
and  `(x-x y)` gets the `x` field of `y` which is 3.
This means that `(+ (x-+ y) (x-x y))` evaluates to 4.

Comment: I was actually doing okay with the field name/struct name being the same. Now that you have explained it however, the confusing part to me is that the notion of _+_ being a function becomes "lost" inside _x_, effectively turning the _+_ into an argument parameter name. I was initially viewing the _struct_ _x_ as an alias for addition.

Comment: @awsunit `+` is just an identifier. in `(+ a b)` `+` is a variable . and `(let ((+ -)) (+ 2 3)) ; ==> -1` Both `binary-search` and `struct` are macros so their arguments are not evaluated normally. `+` is no more special than `x` as both are identifiers.